# bash, how to stdout to file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

How do I force the output of the query into a file from a BASH script?

I have tried

```
 >  file.txt
| >> file.txt
```

and a few more

I keep blowing out syntax errors or just won't work.

```
find fixed/pdf/ -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "Ascend"' \; | 2>&1 dump.txt
```

Comment: Instead of `| 2>&1 dump.txt` try `> dump.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @doh What does `find fixed/pdf/ -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "Ascend"' \;` produce without the redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
find fixed/pdf/ -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "$1" - |
   grep --with-filename --label="$1" --color "Ascend"' - '{}' \; > dump.txt 2>&1
```

To redirect both stdout and stderr to your file `dump.txt`.

Comment: Note that `{}` is not meant to be use that way! It's highly insecure and makes the command subject to code injection. With nearly 300k rep, you should also mention this and show how to use `{}` properly `;)`. Besides, it's also wrong, as POSIX specifies: _If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change._